# Silverlight framework class diagram

Tags: silverlight

Does anyone know where to find a diagram of the classes used in the Silverlight Framework?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class diagram in Visual Studio and add framework classes to it from the class view.
Otherwise [this poster](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=7b645f3a-6d22-4548-a0d8-c2a27e1917f8&displaylang=en) is available for 3.5 but it's not a classes diagram.